# the boundary of a component $C$ of $A$ is contained in the boundary of $A $.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, locally-connected

Let $(Y, \tau)$ be a locally connected topological space and $A\subset Y$. Let $C$ be a component of
$A$. Show that $\partial C\subset \partial A$.

I proved that $Int_{Y}(C)= C\cap Int_{Y}(A)$. Using that,  $x\in \partial C =\overline{C}\setminus Int_{Y}(C)=  \overline{C}\setminus  (C\cap Int_{Y}(A))$, but
$$\overline{C}\setminus  (C\cap Int_{Y}(A))= \overline{C}\cap  (C\cap Int_{Y}(A))^{c}= (\overline{C}\cap  C^{c})\cup (\overline{C}\cap Int_{Y}(A)^{c})$$
I want to show that $x\notin (\overline{C}\cap  C^{c})$. If $x\in (\overline{C}\cap  C^{c})$, then $x$ is a limit point, Using this can I arrive at a contradiction?. or there is direct proof?. thanks

Comment: In general you can’t show that $x\notin(\operatorname{cl}C)\cap(Y\setminus C)$. Let $Y=\Bbb R$ and $C=A=(0,1)$, and let $x=0\in\operatorname{bdry}C$; then $x\in(\operatorname{cl}C)\cap(Y\setminus C)$.

Comment: mmmh I see. The result is true in general?

Comment: I’ve not thought it through carefully, but I think so. If a point is not in the boundary of $A$, it must be either in the interior of $A$ or in the complement of the closure of $A$. In the first case you’ve shown that if it’s in $C$, then it’s in the interior of $C$, not the boundary, so you have only the second case to deal with, and that’s easy.

Comment: I did not understand the first case, if $x \in Int_ {Y} (A)$ and $x\in \partial C$ for what I did in my attempt $x\in \overline{C}\cap C^{c}$  but for your counterexample that can happen. could you explain me please. Thank you

Comment: You’ve shown that $C\cap\operatorname{int}_YA=\operatorname{int}_YC$, so any point that’s in the interior of $A$ and in $C$, then it’s in the interior of $C$, so it can’t be in the boundary of $C$.

Comment: but the case where $x \in\operatorname{ Int}_ {y} (A) $ but not in $C$? how can i conclude? Thank you

Comment: If $x$ is in the interior of $A$, it has a connected nbhd contained in the interior of $A$, and if $x\notin C$, that nbhd cannot intersect the component $C$.

Comment: Ok, if $x\in V\cap C$ since V is connected and $x \ in V $ then $V \ subseteq C$ by definition of $C¢. which contradicts that ¢x \ notin C$. I don't understand why I can conclude that it is not on the boundary of $C$. I'm sorry to bother you

Comment: If $x$ has a nbhd disjoint from $C$, then $x\notin\operatorname{cl}C$.

Comment: I finally understood, thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: You’re very welcome!